# General vs specific "mors" and "vita"

Tags: syntax, word-choice

To my understanding, words like *vita* and *mors* can either refer to the general concepts of life and death ("life is precious", "remember death") or to specific people's lifespans or moments of death ("the lives of the Caesars", "a violent death").

In English, these are distinguished by articles: the general concept doesn't have one, the specific instance does. But Latin doesn't have those.

Is there a common way in Latin to distinguish between general concepts and specific instances like this? Or is it only disambiguated by context (*mors Pompeii* must be a specific instance, while *vita brevis est* could be either life in general or your particular lifespan)?

Comment: Isn't this true for all nouns, not just 'life' and 'death'? Latin also won't distinguish (without additional words) between "a house is expensive" and "his house is expensive." Do you thus want language indicating the general/specific divide or something more specifically (no pun intended) about life and death?

Comment: @cmw To my understanding, a word like _villa_ always refers to an individual house. I might have a particular house in mind or not ("I want to buy the/a/his house"), but it's always an individual house, not the broad concept of house-ness (*I like house)—you need a derivational suffix like -itas for that. _Vita_, though, can be an individual lifetime ("his life was short") or the broad concept of what it means to be alive ("life is the opposite of death").

Comment: I'm not so sure, not yet at least. *Opulentia* can be both abstract (*virtutem opulentia vincit*) and concrete (*opulentia Lydorum*). Maybe if you add enough background to the question to clarify precisely what you mean, that would help.